# How does the Hollow Earth get sunlight?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-vs-kong

Dr Nathan and his team survive the gravity inversion, they land on
the Hollow Earth, which is situated below the Earth's surface:

[image]

How does the Hollow Earth get sunlight?

Comment: [If you listen to the people who actually believe this, apparently it has its own sun](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/agartha-hollow-earth-theory).

Comment: In stories of a hollow Earth (Burroughs' *Pellucidar* and Mike Grell's *Warlord* comic, to name two) there is a small sun at the centre of the Earth. This could work if it had negative mass, hence repelling and being repelled by ordinary mass, explaining why there is outward-pointing gravity at the inner surface. (Of course, it doesn't fit in any way with seismic measurements of our planet, but for fantasy, it is an acceptable explanation.)

Comment: Negative mass has a number of problems as an explanation, beginning with probably not existing and only getting worse from there. Another issue is that a star made of negative mass would be unstable: two particles of negative mass would exert a negative force on each other as a function of the distance between them, just like positive-mass particles, but because Newton's 2nd law also has a negative sign when the mass is negative, this force would be *repulsive*: instead of accelerating toward each other as particles of positive mass would under an attractive force, they would accelerate away.

Comment: To be clear, a star with positive mass (which has the advantage of definitely existing) would not work, either. Although it is less clear, extensive observations and simulations indicate that fusion would not be possible in a star of that size. Its gravitational field would simply not produce sufficient heat or density.

Answer (score 3):

According to an interview with Production Designer Tom Hammock in *[Godzilla vs. Kong: One Will Fall - The Art of the Ultimate Battle Royale](https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Kong:_One_Will_Fall_-_The_Art_of_the_Ultimate_Battle_Royale)* above the interior of the Hollow Earth is a sizeable storm which gives off sufficient light as to replicate sunlight for the inhabitants.

> Because gravity goes haywire inside Hollow Earth's inverted shell, one
> of the only navigational constants is the pulsating storm overhead
> that provides the realm's only source of light. This pseudo-sun shines
> on misted rainforest and pinnacles of black grantite, as the landscape
> curves upwards in every direction. [Sulfur volcanoes in Indonesia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmkmStZc240)
> helped inspire the look of the lightning-lashed central storm. "*They
> give off this strange ebbing purple glow and we
> looked to that as a light source,*" says Hammock
>
> [image]